# FB.Facebook.apiClient.get_session().uid" will work with OAuth2.0 or not?

Tags: facebook, oauth-2.0

Will `FB.Facebook.apiClient.get_session().uid` work with OAuth2.0 migration or not?

How one can test if his application is migrated to OAuth or not?

Answer (score 0):

When you initialise your FB object, just add oauth: true. Then try your code and you will see if it fails - I expect it will as the session object is changing and you will instead have an authResponse. Make sure your app settings on the developer app is switched on for oauth2 migration